# Manipulating DOM in directive, now what?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a directive (inline-edit) and manipulated the DOM in the compile function, but how can I make the other directives that I have added to work? I guess I need to compile it, but how? See my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tidelipop/m4gbZ/
ng-click does not work as it is, but the strange thing is, why do ng-bind work? You can see that it does work if you unhide the textarea in dev tools.

```
angular.module('MyApp', [], function($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.directive("inlineEdit", function($compile, $q){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: true,
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.editMode = true;
                $scope.save = function(){
                    console.log("Saving...");
                };
            },
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
                tElement
                    .attr("ng-hide", "editMode")
                    .attr("ng-click", "editMode=!editMode")
                    .after("<textarea ng-show=\"editMode\" ng-model=\""+tAttrs.ngBind+"\"></textarea><button ng-click=\"save()\">Save</button>");

                //var scopeResolver = $q.defer();
                //$compile(tElement.parent().contents())(scopeResolver.promise);

                return function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
                    //scopeResolver.resolve(scope);
                    //$compile(element.parent().contents())(scope);
                    console.log(element.parent().contents());
                };
            }
        };
    });
})


.controller("UserAdminCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.data_copy = {
        user: {
            user_id: 'sevaxahe',
            comment: 'test'
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Think I solved it! Is this the correct way of doing this? http://jsfiddle.net/tidelipop/uEj7c/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m4gbZ/74/ working solution. Lots of modifications, and be careful, I used angular 1.2. I don't even know if it will help you, I will come back with more infos if no other solution is found (no time to improve my response, sorry :/ )

Comment: Thanks! Now we have three working solutions, I'll look at them.

Comment: Why doesn't it work if I want the ng-bind directive on the original html? I saw you put it directly in inline-edit instead.

Comment: Anyway, this is great! Started modifing it some more now.Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/tidelipop/wyjdT/

Comment: I can explain my solution if you want in few hours ( I'm on my phone right now )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your directive is conflicting with the ng-bind, I don't really know why, but the question I asked myself looking at your code was : Wouldn't it be easier using a template and a custon attribute for the model (instead of ng-bind) ?
And the answer is yes !
Actually that's just my opinion, but here is what I did by modifying your code http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/m4gbZ/73/
I let you have a look, I had to change some parts (the ng-click doesn't work well on the textarea so I put this behavior on the Save button) but I think this is almost what you wanted.  On code side, I modified the HTML to avoid calling ng-bind, using a custom scope variable which will be caught in the directive :

```
<span inline-edit ff="data_copy.user.comment">First</span>
```

On the directive side, I got rid of all the compile/controller stuff, and I added a template

```
return {
        restrict: "A",
        template:'<div><span ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode=!editMode">{{aModel}}</span><textarea ng-show="editMode" ng-model="aModel"></textarea> <button ng-click="save()">{{getLabel()}}</button></div>',
        replace:true,
        scope: {aModel:'=ff'},
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log(element)
            scope.editMode = true;
            scope.save = function(){
                console.log("Saving...");
                scope.editMode=!scope.editMode;
                };
            scope.getLabel=function(){
             if(scope.editMode)
                 return "Save";
             else
                 return "Change";
            }
            console.log(element.parent().contents());
            }

    }
```

Why ? The template, because angular will compile it itself without any intervention.
I added `replace:true` to replace the line, but it's optionnal

The scope part is more important. `scope: {'=ff'}` tells angular that I want to use an isolated scope, and I want the scope.aModel value to be bound with the ff variable passed in the HTML.
The '=' means that the modifications will be evaluated from the parent scope, and every modification will be reflected in the parent and in the directive

I replaced your controller and your compile function (no element to compile, and adding function can be done here instead of a dedicated controller) by a linking function containing the functions needed. As I said before, I added the editMode change behavior to the Save button, so I added a bit more code, but it's not the main point, I think you may have to change things here to reflect your expected behavior

I hope this will help you, as I don't really answer your question, but I think you could also explore this way

++

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting to see different solutions. I'll look into the differences from the above.